# Why Date time value change when contain data hit on controller action? Using AngularJs and Asp.Net Web API 2

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I send data from client side to server side, two property of date time type "ReviewStartDate" and "ReviewEndDate" change. Two property date time is not change in client side. But the server side two property value has changed. **how can solved this issue very well?**

Client side send data screenshot [image: Client side debug screenshot]

Server side debug screenshot when hit on controller action [image: Server side debug screenshot]

After converting to local time [image]

Here is my Model Class

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReviewStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReviewEndDate { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddProduct")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        return Ok(services.AddProduct(product).Data);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like `ReviewStartDate` and `ReviewEndDate` parameter values are converted to UTC date, because both dates are subtracted by 6 hours in time part as indicated in the image. You may want to pass them as UTC/ISO time and convert them to local time afterwards.

Comment: Where  I converting this?

Comment: Exact similar Issue I have faced, not abe to know where the date gets subtracted by 6 hrs

Answer (score 0):

First of all on clint side, before sending data to the server, you convert it to UTC. But you did not show your front-end code, i can't figure out where.

But if i correctly understand you, you want to convert utc to local time and do that only on server side. (**it`s will be work, but honestly better change client side**)

You can change json options in startup file:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(
                opt => opt.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

for example i send this:

"execution_date": "2019-02-20T00:00:00.000Z" - utc

and serialize like this, for my local time:

2/20/19 3:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

Angular while calling post method do this conversion.
Going through Angular Documentation on GitHub, it's community developers says that it was not by Angular , this conversion is done by JSON serialization as per its ISO standards.

From a Point it is true,

- Suppose you are in New York and saving your Grade at 12:00 PM ET, it
  will got to back-end Server and will be saved in Database as 4:00 PM
  UTC.
- When your friend in San Francisco tries to access your records on UI 
  browser , he will see it as Grade was saved as 9:00 AM PT.

This Makes
   sense to me .

But if you want your friend also want to see Grade saved at 12:00 PM then you have to do some hack.

I spent several hours and figure out there are some 3rd party libraries like moment.js with which we can work around .

But the solutions to this problem is

**Post**

on UI

1) Convert your Datetime to string and send this string to backend

```
Date date = new Date();
var d = date.toDateString();
```

2) Convert back this String to Datetime and save in DB.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(d)
```

**Get**

on Server

1) Convert Datetime (it is in UTC) backend to String.

```
DateTime dateTime = //from DataBase
Strind d = dateTime.ToString()
```

on UI

2) Fetch this string from Backend to client ui and convert back to Datetime

```
Date date = new Date(d);
```